# preLaunchTask " " terminated with exit code -1

Tags: c++, json, gdb, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to debug a C++ file in VSCode, I followed all the instructions of VSCode but this always shows up. I am using Windows 10. If I click  ***Debug Anyway*** It will not hit any breakpoint. How do I fix it?  [The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pt14.png).

[This is my cpp file (so you can also see the explorer tab).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFaqk.png)

This is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> msg {"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code", "and the C++ extension!"};

    for (const string& word : msg)
    {
        cout << word << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the directory to the c++ file.

***C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\Program\CppNew\helloworld.cpp***

I use this option to debug in VSCode
[g++.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgueY.png)

```
{ //tasks.json
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "BuildProject",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\helloworld.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

```
{ //launch.json
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C/C++: g++.exe build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "BuildProject"
        }
    ]
}
```

My Debugging Console Log

```
=thread-group-added,id="i1"
GNU gdb (GDB) 12.1
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-w64-mingw32".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
Warning: Debuggee TargetArchitecture not detected, assuming x86_64.
=cmd-param-changed,param="pagination",value="off"

Thread 1 hit Breakpoint 1, 0x00007ff7e987146c in main ()
Loaded 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgcc_s_seh-1.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libstdc++-6.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Execute debugger commands using "-exec <command>", for example "-exec info registers" will list registers in use (when GDB is the debugger)
Single stepping until exit from function main,
which has no line number information.
[Thread 11160.0x2ff4 exited with code 0]
[Thread 11160.0x459c exited with code 0]
[Thread 11160.0x37bc exited with code 0]
[Inferior 1 (process 11160) exited normally]
The program 'c:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\Program\CppNew\helloworld.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x00000000).
```

These are my g++, gcc, and gdb versions.

***g++ (Rev7, Built by MSYS2 project) 12.2.0***

***gcc (Rev7, Built by MSYS2 project) 12.2.0***

***GNU gdb (GDB) 12.1***

This is my directory to bin (also in my PATH)

***C:\msys64\mingw64\bin***

I tried reinstalling mingw through msys2 but it still didn't work. I tried putting absolute values in

```
    "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
```

but it says my file does not exist.

Update:
I change this from tasks.json

```
 "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\Program\\CppNew"
            },
```

Also changed this from launch.json

```
 "program": "C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\Program\\CppNew\\helloworld.exe",
"cwd": "C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\Program\\CppNew",
```

It is also active when I try to click the debug button.
[image: active]

Tried restarting VSCode after I input the absolute values.
Still not working. Same error.

Comment: your code seems OK but maybe you should paste it here as text

Comment: Done! I pasted it

Comment: Nothing is really standing out to me, but one thing that needs to be double-checked is whether the code file itself is the active file when you attempt to debug.

Comment: And if that's not it, I'd recommend never opening a file in VS Code. Always open a folder, and then change your variables to use the `{workspace*}` flavors. VS Code really expects a "workspace," i.e., you've opened a folder that contains your project.

Comment: "Single stepping until exit from function main,
which has no line number information.": that means that you're missing debug switches when you're building your app. But your options include "-g" so....

Comment: problem matcher isn't the regex to match errors? why is it `$gcc` and not `^gcc` ? and why are those json config files so complex? VS json config really sucks. Have you tried `gdb yourprogram.exe` in a command line?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Those jsons are pre-generated. You typically only have to make very small changes to them. My current conclusion is wondering if OP's environment is correct. They mention reinstalling, but did they reboot? Getting a proper mingw environment set up is non-trivial as well. My usual recommendation is to go the WSL route as VS Code can seamlessly integrate with it.

Comment: yes, ironically VS code works better from Linux that from Windows...